# Modify HTTP header and redirect to other web application (cross applications)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, http-headers

I found some skills to modify http header, but they are not what I need.
I am writing a web application which **modifies** the http header and **redirects** to destination web application. Cross application is the problem.

My solution:

Create a `Valve` in Tomcat, to modify the header in `org.apache.catalina.Valve.invoke(Request, Response)`. The the request header is modified prior to web application.

Any better idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean 'redirecting' in a way that the client is not aware it? Sounds like reverse proxying.
In such case, you can write [HttpServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) and in its `service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)` method rewrite request parameters and perform request to the destination service (using HttpClient for example). This is platform independent solution since you don't base on Apache's Catalina. However, both these solutions (servlet, valves and probably all others) have some drawbacks. Proxying and modifying requests on the fly is not so simple as many tutorials about it describes, especially when it comes to aspects as streaming or encoding (if you want to modify content also).

Comment: Do you mean call HttpClient API in service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)?

Comment: In the simplest form of a reverse proxy - yes. If there were more complex scenarios involved, it would probably evolve into separate proxy project.